# Check if date in one table appears in range in another table in Access

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a query in MS Access 2010 where I have two tables (Patients, Phantoms) and I'm trying to find if a date within the Phantoms table was acquired for a specific site on the Patients table within +/- 10 days of a patient scan.

The Patients table just has site, patient ID and scan receive date.

For every site number, we have to acquire a phantom. The Phantoms table has the site number and the receive date of the phantom.

I would like to write a query where the site number from the Patients table is joined to the site number in the Phantoms table, and it checks that the receive date for the Phantom is +/- 7 days from the scan receipt date in the Patients table.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What exactly did you want the output of your query to show?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your date fields in both tables are of the type `Date/Time`, let me know if they are not.

There are a couple of ways that you can get the difference between two dates. One way would be to manually check the conditions with some simple math.

```
SELECT Patient.[Patient ID], Patient.Site, Patient.[Scan Recieved], Phantom.[Receive Date]
FROM Patient INNER JOIN Phantom ON Patient.Site = Phantom.[Site Number]
WHERE (((Patient.[Scan Recieved]-Phantom.[Receive Date])<=7 
    AND (Patient.[Scan Recieved]-Phantom.[Receive Date])>=0)) 
OR (((Phantom.[Receive Date]-Patient.[Scan Recieved])<=7 
 AND (Phantom.[Receive Date]-Patient.[Scan Recieved])>=0))
```

Another possibility would be to use the [DateDiff](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx) function, which makes things a bit simpler.

```
SELECT Patient.[Patient ID], Patient.Site, Patient.[Scan Recieved], Phantom.[Receive Date]
FROM Patient INNER JOIN Phantom ON Patient.Site = Phantom.[Site Number]
WHERE DateDiff("d", Patient.[Scan Recieved], Phantom.[Receive Date]) <=7
```

The `"d"` parameter will ouput the number of days between the other two parameters.